# Cross between csr matrix and an index

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, matrix

I have the following index:

```
Index(['z_2', 'z_3',     # first location, the numbers after the _ are redundant
       'z_4', 'z_5',
       'z_6', 'z_7',
       'z_8', 'z_9',
       'z_10', 'z_11',
       ...
       'r_4509', 'r_4538',
       'r_4306', 'r_4583',
       'r_1232', 'r_4592',
       'r_4601', 'r_4610',
       'r_4637', 'r_4627'],
      dtype='object', length=45590)
```

In addition, the follow csr matrix:

```
  (1, 29163)    0.06            # <- z location 0, r location 29163
  (3, 29161)    0.14            # <- z location 3, r location 29161
  (4, 29160)    0.11
  (5, 29159)    0.21
....           ...
  (44336, 18216)    0.01
  (44396, 15050)    0.02
  (44440, 16356)    0.24
  (44461, 531)      0.04
```

Note: The numbers in csr_matrix are actually locations. The z_ data has about 24k rows, while the r_ data has 21k. So then, the first 'csr_matrix' row actually indicates on z_2 (which is the first value in index) and the 29163th value in r_data.
**I am trying to find a way to replace location number with the corresponding string from the index**. The numbers near that are scores. What did I tried: EDITED partial answer

```
import anndata as ad
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
var_names = pd.DataFrame(matrix.adata.var_names)

col1 = pd.DataFrame(matrix.tgf.tocoo().row ) # 29163, 29161,29160..
col2 = pd.DataFrame(matrix.tgf.tocoo().col ) # 1,3,4
# index to location intersection
z = var_names.index.intersection(col1.iloc[:,0])
r = var_names.index.intersection(col2.iloc[:,0])

var_names.loc[z] = var_names
var_names['z'] = col1.iloc[:,0]
var_names.loc[r] = var_names
var_names['r'] = col2.iloc[:,0]
col1['var'] = z
col2['var'] = r
#var_names['col1'] = col1.iloc[0]
#var_names['col2'] = col2.iloc[0]
print(var_names[:5])
                       0   z    r
                   0  z_2  1  29163
                   1  z_3  3  29161
                   2  z_4  4  29160
                   3  z_5  5  29159
                   4  z_6  6  41784
```

But then I struggles, as I don't have any experience with csr_matrices

*edited: r column doesn't corresponding to r_ even though I did the intersection with col2.

Answer (score 0):

```
var_names = pd.DataFrame(matrix.adata.var_names, columns = ['features'])

#This is the most important part to extract both "columns"- like from matrix
col1 = pd.DataFrame(matrix.tgf.tocoo().row, columns = ['features'])
col2 = pd.DataFrame(matrix.tgf.tocoo().col, columns = ['features'])

#Intersection between each data (z_ or r_) with the matrix (var_names)
col2['features'] = col2['features'].map(var_names.set_index(var_names.index)['features'])
col1['features'] = col1['features'].map(var_names.set_index(var_names.index)['features'])
col1 = col1.loc[col1.index.isin(col2.index)]
col1['r']= col2['features']
print(col1)
```

#Matched by index location

```
       z_3                    r_15654
1      z_5                    r_25472
2      z_6                    r_15412
3      z_7                    r_15468
4      z_8                    r_12
```